# Can I be confident of my $R^2$ score?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, correlation, r-squared

I have a dataset with 10 variables and 158 observations.

I used cross-validation, grid-search and ElasticNet algorithm.

To evaluate the model I checked the Pearson correlation between the 10 variables and known output. The correlation is not good, but the model $R^2$ score is near 0.98.

How can I be confident in my $R^2 $value? Because I didn't expect an $R^2$ like this. This is higher that I expected.

Comment: An $R^2$ so high is very unusual and you are right to be wary. Check the correlation between your explanatory variables and your dependent variable. If one of them is very high, investigate why this happens. Check Spearman's $\rho$ too. Please clarify what you mean by "*the correlation is not good.*". Also please consider presenting the model summary so we can have more information.

Answer (score 4):

When you perform a regression on the ten variables, you are using all of them together to predict the outcome. Thus, each variable can, on its own, be a rather poor predictor that has fairly low correlation with the outcome. For instance, in the simulation below, I get an $R^2$ close to your value of $0.98$, yet the correlations between individual variables and the outcome are all around $0.3$.

```r
set.seed(2023)
N <- 158
p <- 10
X <- matrix(rnorm(N * p), N, p)
B <- rep(1, p)
Ey <- X %*% B
e <- rnorm(N, 0, 0.5)
y <- Ey + e
L <- lm(y ~ X)
cors <- rep(NA, p)
for (i in 1:p){
    cors[i] <- cor(X[, i], y)
    print(cors[i])
}
summary(L)$r.squared # I get almost 0.98
summary(cors) # Range from 0.236 to 0.38
```

While $R^2=0.98$ is suspiciously high for some fields, the goal of predictive modeling is to make accurate predictions. If you validate the performance (some kind of out-of-sample testing or [bootstrap](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/563390/is-it-valid-to-do-roc-analysis-without-using-test-data/563402#563402), perhaps a congratulations is in order for getting a model to reliably make such accurate predictions!

Comment: I think it's a little misleading to suggest a multiple regression where all the univariate regression coefficients are zero could have a large $R^2$ or even a nonzero $R^2.$ That observation relies on sometimes counting nonlinear combinations of the original variables among the explanatory features and sometimes not. The only meaningful comparison here would include *all* features. Another issue concerns your misleadingly large choice of $n:$ $10000$ is *hugely* greater than the $158$ reported in the question.

Comment: @whuber I do not see where I suggest anything about how the coefficients are zero. In this example, all of the coefficients are one. // I dropped the sample size to 158 and got pretty similar results of $R^2\approx 0.98$ and the individual correlations between $0.236$ and $0.380$, so slightly different but not alarmingly so.

Comment: "Coefficients are zero" is equivalent to zero pairwise correlations, which is the extreme case of "poor predictor."

Comment: @whuber Do you mean when I write about nonlinear basis functions?

Comment: What I find misleading is the assertion "the individual variables might have zero correlation with the outcome, yet the combination of the features and polynomial functions (or other nonlinear functions) might explain everything." It's correct but it's irrelevant because it introduces a procedure outside the scope of the question; namely, adjoining new features to the regression.

Comment: @whuber That is fair. Removed.

Comment: +1. For more insight, consider (approximately) orthonormal explanatory variables $X_1,\ldots, X_k$ and let $y = X_1+\cdots X_k + \varepsilon$ where $\varepsilon$ has a tiny variance. That ensures the regression of $y$ on the $X_j$ has (arbitrarily) high $R^2,$ while the individual correlation coefficients are $\operatorname{Cor}(y,X_j)\approx 1/\sqrt{k}.$ With $k=10,$ that gives plausibly "not good" correlations around $0.32.$ I believe that explains what your code is doing.